# Relative path of image not working in angular cli

Tags: html, angular-cli

First of all I am new to Angular, and I have never faced this kind of issue in simple MVC. I am working on it from last 4 hours and still not resolved.

> I want to use below marked image in my HTML.

[image]

my angularcli.json file looks like this.

[image]

and this is how I am accessing the image.

```
<img src="assets/img/user-medium.png" class="img-circle" alt="Avatar">
```

any kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `angular-cli.json` to

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

and use the following

```
<img src="/assets/img/user-medium.png" class="img-circle" alt="Avatar">
```

Comment: did you try deleting the browser cache and then trying

Comment: @Bharatcan you just try the chrome developer tools and adjust the image path on the go if it takes it or not ? because this should work

Comment: yes, on the fly it works, and that's the most interesting and crazy behaviour of angular..

Comment: on the fly this path works you are saying , it has to do with component cache i feel of the editor, it happens with vscode i have seen if you are using one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153587/discussion-between-bharat-and-rahul-singh).